# Properties in manifest

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, websphere, war

IBM Cognos generates EAR file which includes a lot of JARs in /WEB-INF/lib/

Of those JARs, a few (namely, idvisualizations_helpers.jar and some others) in their /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF contain the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: jvmwi3260sr10-20111207_96808 (IBM Corporation)
Main-Class: ${project.main.class}
Class-Path: ${relative.classpath}
```

Is this valid? I mean, who will be responsible for expanding those {} placeholders? To me this does not even make any sense: if software executing the JAR knows its main class, there is no reason to mention it in Manifest.
I can only think of two explanations. First, this is a plain and simple bug, a failure to substitute those placeholders when making a JAR. Second, such a notation is valid and assumes that the JVM using that JAR will provide values for those placeholders (but I don't believe in this, as specifying different value for each such JAR would be too inconvenient).

Someone please explain what does that mean. More practical part of the problem is that on Websphere Liberty 8.5.5 an error is produced because of "${relative.classpath}" not being a valid URI. I wonder why that does not happen on another environment running full Websphere (though the Cognos configuration there differs from mine).

Comment: What is the error message you get from Liberty?

Comment: It's URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${relative.classpath}

Comment: Oh, there is one more thing to add. Not only am I running Liberty while the other system is full Websphere, but also I am using Oracle JRE and another system is using IBM's (under /IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre). I will check if that's the reason. Maybe IBM's is expanding the placeholders (probably making them empty but at least valid) or ignoring them.

Comment: I'd guess it is a build variable substitution issue rather than a JVM difference.

Comment: @MaksimGumerov did you ever solve your problem? I am trying to add property placeholders into my manifest files.

Comment: @Jesse You have to understand I never wanted the placeholders to work, I just was not being able to run Cognos because of them :) I don't remember how it all resolved in the end, sorry. Maybe it was my mistake and I did not wholly configure Cognos and that's why it was generating wrong EARs. Too much time passed :(

Answer (score 1):

No, having properties in your *final* manifest that is used by the Java JVM is not valid based on the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes). When I say "final" I mean you might have properties in your manifest as part of your source code which are then filtered out during the build and replaced with the values of those properties. This is perfectly fine. Another possibility is that there may some post-build processing that replaces those properties with the correct values.

You said:

> ...on Websphere Liberty 8.5.5 an error is produced because of "${relative.classpath}" not being a valid URI. I wonder why that does not happen on another environment running full Websphere (though the Cognos configuration there differs from mine).

I'm not quite clear on what you meant with that last part about the Cognos configuration differing from yours, but it sounds like you're saying that the manifest you showed in your question is working on one platform but not on another. I would imagine that either one platform is performing post processing or the two platforms have different deployed code somehow. I suggest going back and confirming that you have the exact same manifest in both platforms and debug your build process to try to find where those variables' values are obtained and when.

Please see [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) for more information about the manifest file.

Comment: I've checked that, the JAR's manifest was the same on both systems even though the containing EAR differed on them. Any references to known examples of such post-processing in real software?

Comment: I'm not sure if any platforms really do post-processing or not, it was just a possibility that came to mind. However, I know that sometimes a deployment process may involve post processing for the purpose of localizing variables to the environment where the application is to be deployed.

Comment: There is also another possibility here: some platforms may always or optionally ignore such errors in manifests. Say, application servers will most probably use their custom classloaders etc which I think can theoretically silently skip such problems or not read manifests whatsoever. But theories will not give me a quick answer. What I need at the moment is firm answer like "yes it's wrong but full Websphere (or Tomcat etc) will accept it" or maybe "Liberty can also accept it if you do smth" or "Tomcat will expand those placeholders"...

Comment: I see, well I can't say for sure as I don't know enough about those specific platforms and how they deal with manifest files. I would recommend that you edit your question to reflect what you just said here because it seems the real question is "Why does this manifest work on platform A but not on platform B?"